# is sumac offered kosher for Passover?

Tags: passover

Been looking on grocery shelves for the last few years. Does anyone know if sumac is kosher for Passover? If it requires certification?

Comment: Yes it is kosher lepesach: https://www.crcweb.org/spice_list.php

Comment: R'David Cohen explains that many blends require certification. But, spices that just contain 1 sort, do not. - https://www.crcweb.org/kosher_articles/spice_blends.php

Comment: @Shmuel The crcweb.org list contains the comment, "This list should not be used for Passover."

Comment: Did not notice that, thank you for the heads up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pereg offer a sumac with supervision for Passover. See [here](https://www.glattkosherstore.com/kosher-pereg-sumac-4-2-oz) .

Comment: Thanks. Guess I better do my shopping earlier!